# How to force Nginx to override PHP CGI HTTP Status code?

Tags: php, nginx, http-headers, fastcgi

In Nginx + PHP-FPM configuration I have a `.php` file with the following content:

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed");
echo 'hi';
?>
```

Now, if I want to force Nginx to ignore such this HTTP Status codes originating from PHP scripts, what should I do in Nginx config file? In other words, I want to Nginx dismiss custom status headers and ignore them (replace them with `Status: 200 OK` i.e.).
I have read Nginx documentation about fastcgi and didn't find any useful directive for this purpose. Also, [fastcgi_intercept_errors](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_intercept_errors) is not the solution.

Comment: this might be helpful ... https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module#more_set_headers not 100% sure so leaving as a comment rather than an answer

Comment: The only way to force Nginx to change the PHP status code is with `fastcgi_intercept_errors`.

Comment: @RichardSmith I'm not agree with you. `fastcgi_intercept_errors` just renders HTTP errors in the manner defined with `error_log` directive.

Comment: They are processed by the `error_page` directive, which allows you to change the status code.